# How to use variable in tag flag in docker build command?

Tags: docker, automation, dockerfile

I want to automate my docker build process.
Every time I build it, I want it to tag it using the environment variable.

For ex.

```
export image_version=v2.0.0

docker build -t imagename:image_version .
```

How can I do this? I tried `$` but it is throwing error as `invalid reference format`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `${}` syntax:

```
$ export image_version=v2.0.0
$ docker build -t imagename:${image_version} .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/1 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
  ---> 3556258649b2
 Successfully built 3556258649b2
 Successfully tagged imagename:v2.0.0
```